# How to initialize CNN Layer with Gammatone Filters (or any filter) for sound regression (Or Classification)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, signal-processing, filter-bank

For my project I need to initialize the CNN 1st Layer kernel with Gammatone filters according to papers ( https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/20/12/990/htm ) ,( https://www.groundai.com/project/end-to-end-environmental-sound-classification-using-a-1d-convolutional-neural-network/1 ) and a few others. What does it exactly mean to initialize the cnn kernel with Gammatone filter (Or any filter). How does one implement it? Is it a custom layer? Any tips and guidance would be much appreciated!

for instance

```
conv_1 = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = *insert Gammatone Filter*, padding = 'same', activation='relu', input_shape = (timesteps, features))(decoder_outputs3)
```

TIA

Comment: Hi. Can you please guide me on how you got the Gammatone Filterbank values to initialize the CNN 1st layer? Thanks

Comment: If you got on answer, please let me known because I need the answer to the same your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use TensorFlows [constant initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer):

```
gammatone_filter_kernel = np.array([...])
init_kernel = tf.constant_initializer(gammatone_filter_kernel)
# ...
conv_1 = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = init_kernel, padding = 'same', activation='relu', input_shape = (timesteps, features))(decoder_outputs3)
# ...
```

If your filter is some kind of preprocessing step to your signal you could set the `trainable` attribute of the conv laver to `False` and the weights will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this! Didn't know about constant initializers! I'll definitely try it.