# Bottleneck Feature extraction for phonemes in language translation model using machine learning

Tags: audio, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have built a basic encoder decoder model architecture for language translation directly from audio speeches but it desperately needs some increase in performance/accuracy. The only thing I have not been able to achieve is extracting the bottleneck features from the input audio files and taking it forward to the decoder via the attention mechanism.

I'm very new to this. I came across the Bottleneck Feature Extractor (https://github.com/iondel/multilingual-bottleneck-features) and Kaldi's ASR toolkit ( https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi ). The first one uses .scp files made in Kaldi style from what I could understand. I was wondering if someone could tell me in as simple language as possible, as to how do I use these amazing toolkits (Or any other out there, or any other tips) to extract phoneme features from my input audio spectrogram and send it forward in the pipeline to the decoder?

My pipeline:-

```
#VoiceConversionSeq2Seq - https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06865
inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, features))

#Encoder
#masked_encoder_inputs = layers.Masking(mask_value=0)(inputs)
encoder_out1,f_h1, f_c1, b_h1, b_c1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dimE, return_sequences = True, return_state=True))(inputs)
encoder_out2,f_h2, f_c2, b_h2, b_c2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dimE, return_sequences = True, return_state=True))(encoder_out1)
encoder_out2 = LayerNormalization()(encoder_out2)
state_h2 = Concatenate()([f_h2, b_h2])
state_c2 = Concatenate()([f_c2, b_c2])
encoder_states = [state_h2, state_c2]

#PreNet
NN_1 = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(encoder_out2)
drop1 = Dropout(rate = 0.5)(NN_1)
NN_2 = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(NN_1)
drop2 = Dropout(rate = 0.5)(NN_2)


#Attention
att_out = MultiHeadAttention(head_num=4)(drop2)

#Decoder
#decoder_inputs = att_out#RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoder_outputs)
decoder_inputs = att_out
decoder_lstm1 = LSTM(latent_dimD*2,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs1, _, _ = decoder_lstm1(decoder_inputs, initial_state = encoder_states)

decoder_lstm2 = LSTM(latent_dimD*2,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs2, _, _ = decoder_lstm2(decoder_outputs1, initial_state = encoder_states)

decoder_lstm3 = LSTM(latent_dimD*2,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs3, _, _ = decoder_lstm3(decoder_outputs2, initial_state = encoder_states)

#PostNet
conv_1 = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = gammaT(decoder_outputs3), padding = 'same', activation='relu', input_shape = (timesteps, features))(decoder_outputs3)
drop3 = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(conv_1)
conv_2 = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(drop3)
drop4 = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(conv_2)
conv_3 = Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(drop4)
drop5 = Dropout(rate = 0.2)(conv_3)

NN_3 = Dense(timesteps, activation = 'softmax')(drop5)

decoder_outputs = Dense(features, activation = 'relu')(NN_3)

model = Model(inputs, decoder_outputs)
#encoder = Model(inputs, encoder_outputs)
```

Things I need to add :-

a. Gammatone filter in the first conv1d postnet layer (I'm still struggling with this) - I have posted it here - [How to initialize CNN Layer with Gammatone Filters (or any filter) for sound regression (Or Classification)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796298/how-to-initialize-cnn-layer-with-gammatone-filters-or-any-filter-for-sound-reg/61796590#61796590)

b. Phoneme bottleneck feature extraction after Encoder to send it forward down the pipeline along with encoder states and output.

Any help/tip is highly appreciated. Ask me any sort of questions regarding the code